# regex matching image url with spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I need to match a image url like this:

```
http://site.com/site.com/files/images/img (5).jpg
```

Something like this works fine:

```
.replace(/(http:\/\/([ \S]+\.(jpg|png|gif)))/ig, "<div style=\"background: url($1)\"></div>")
```

Except if I have something like this:

```
http://site.com/site.com/files/audio/audiofile.mp3 http://site.com/site.com/files/images/img (5).jpg
```

How do I match only the image?

Thanks!

Edit: And I'm using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper URLs should not have spaces in them, they should have `%20` or a plus `'+'` instead. If you had them written with those alternatives then your matching would be much easier.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't make all my users edit their files with spaces to include %20.

Comment: @mark... your users shouldn't rename the files.. whatever you use to get the file from the users should be doing it as the files come in.

Comment: Maybe someone wants to write a regex to find all the urls that have spaces so they can replace them with %20's. Telling someone they shouldn't have a problem isn't solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming images will always be in the 'images' directory, try:

```
http://.*/images/(.*?).(jpe?g|gif|png)
```

If you can't assume an images directory:

```
http://.*/(.*?).(jpe?g|gif|png)
```

Group 1 and 2 should have what you want (file name and extension).

I tested the regular expression [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.jsp) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) and it appears to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks but I can't assume the images directory. The image could be coming from anywhere. :(

Comment: Not a huge deal. I suggest you test this regex (use the link I posted). It should give you an idea of what information you will get.

Comment: Thanks, but that's very similar to what I have. It matches the entire line of: http://site.com/site.com/files/audio/audiofile.mp3 http://site.com/site.com/files/images/img (5).jpg rather than just the image.

Comment: Yes, it matches the line, but the captured groups will grab the image (img (5), and jpg). What is wrong with matching the line?

Comment: I'm trying to match the url of the image. I've updated my example to show more clearly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
/([^/]+\.(jpg|png|gif))$
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
http:\/\/.*\/(.*)\.(jpg|png|gif)
```

should do the trick if all you want is the name of the image. The first group is the file name and the second group is the file extension.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to match the entire url.

Comment: You should probably mention that above as it confused a few of us.

Answer (score 0):

Can you assume that the urls will be space delimited, or return delimited?

As in, can you assume this input?

```
site.com/images/images/lol (5).jpg
site.com/images/other/radio.mp3
site.com/images/images/copter (3).jpg
```

If you are going to have your delimiter as part of your string to return, things get tricky. What kind of volume are you talking about here? Could you do it semi-manually at all, or does the process have to be automated?

Comment: Yes there will always be a white space after the file extension. And I know how horrible it is to have that in the url itself.

Perhaps a 2 step process to make the spaces first into %20 might be a good idea.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. Unless you have a definite separator between your image stirngs, like \n, you can't distinguish between site.com\images\img and (5).jpg

Comment: Thanks, do you have a good way to convert the spaces? I think what I was trying to do in my answer is glitchy.

Comment: maybe just convert any space that doesn't follow with 'site.com' with %20?

Answer (score 0):

This would be an approach:

```
^((\w+):)?\/\/((\w|\.)+(:\d+)?)[^:]+\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$
```

Mathing on the colon. (:)
In this case it's only accepted for the protocol and port (optional).

This will not match:

```
http://site.com/site.com/files/audio/audiofile.mp3 http://site.com/site.com/files/images/img (5).jpg
```

This will match (colon in second http:// removed)

"**/audiofile.mp3 http/**" will count as a folder in "**/audio/**"

```
http://site.com/site.com/files/audio/audiofile.mp3 http//site.com/site.com/files/images/img (5).jpg
```

It's not fool proof. There are other characters that are not allowed in filenames ( *** | " < >** )