# Regex to change spaces in images into entities

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

I'm having a lot of difficulty matching an image url with spaces.

I need to make this

```
http://site.com/site.com/files/images/img 2 (5).jpg
```

into a div like this:

```
.replace(/(http:\/\/([^\s]+\.(jpg|png|gif)))/ig, "<div style=\"background: url($1)\"></div>")
```

Here's the thread about that:
[regex matching image url with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066697/regex-matching-image-url-with-spaces)

Now I've decided to first make the spaces into entities so that the above regex will work.

But I'm really having a lot of difficulty doing so.
Something like this:

```
.replace(/http:\/\/(.*)\/([^\<\>?:;]*?) ([^\<\>?:;]*)(\.(jpe?g|png|gif))/ig, "http://$1/$2%20$3$4")
```

Replaces one space, but all the rest are still spaces.

I need to write a regex that says, make all spaces between http:// and an image extension (png|jpg|gif) into %20.

At this point, frankly not sure if it's even possible. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Trying Paolo's escape:

```
.escape(/http:\/\/(.*)\/([^\<\>?:;]*?) ([^\<\>?:;]*)(\.(jpe?g|png|gif))/)
```

Another way I can do this is to escape serverside in PHP, and in PHP I can directly mess with the file name without having to match it in regex.

But as far as I know something like htmlentities do not apply to spaces. Any hints in this direction would be great as well.

Comment: You have to call escape on whatever string you are calling the regex on...

Comment: What string? I need to match an(y) image url.

Comment: You need to match it against what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to control the replacement character but don't want to use a regular expression, a simple...

```
$destName = str_replace(' ', '-', $sourceName);
```

..would probably be the more efficient solution.

Comment: This is what worked for me, thanks.

though I replaced it with %20.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [escape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) function:

```
>>> escape("test you");
test%20you
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have the string variable `urlWithSpaces` which is set to a URL which contains spaces.

Simply go:

```
urlWithoutSpaces = escape(urlWithSpaces);
```

Comment: The issue is, by the time I get to do something with client side, the url will be part of a post that the user submitted, so I would have to match it first.

Answer (score 0):

What about urlencode() - that may do what you want.

Comment: Oh, and rawurlencode () may be more appropriate with the space encodings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, though that encodes too much. When '/' becomes %2F the url refuses to work.

Answer (score 0):

On the JS side you should be using [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURI), and escape() only as a fallback. The reason to use encodeURI() is that it uses UTF-8 for encoding, while escape() uses ISO Latin. Same problems applies for decoding.

```
encodeURI = encodeURI || escape;

alert(encodeURI('image name.png'));
```